# Print with rotation in Adobe LiveCycle ES4

Tags: printing, rotation, livecycle

I'm designing an utility with Adobe LiveCycle ES4 and I want to perform printing utility:

Is it possible to print the document with a 90º rotation?

Now I'm using a form with a print button but I'm not able to find this utility in the menus neither in the function written in the xml file.

Lots of thanks for helping me!

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail?  Are you using LiveCycle Designer?  Have you tried going to the Master Page object properties and changing the page orientation?

In general, you design your form so that the on-screen appearance matches the print appearance.  You normally don't need to rotate the print.  Instead you design the form in landscape orientation.

Perhaps if you provided more details about why you are trying to print in a different orientation, it would help me provide a workaround.

Comment: Yes, I'm using LiveCycle Designer. If I change the page orientation in Master Page the text is not rotated. The reason which motivates me to rotate the print is that I need to print it with a special printer and with a special sheet of paper. Thanks!